# Why does android:autofillHints in styles.xml shows a warning but not in layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a simple layout on login screen and inside, there are `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Email"
        android:id="@+id/etEmailLayout"
        android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            style="@style/TextInputEditText.Email"
            android:id="@+id/etEmail" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

There is no problem with this layout. Except that when I move the attribute `android:autofillHints` to the style.xml I will get this error:

[image]

And it wouldn't be a problem if it could be resolved somehow, but IDE give me these options:
[image]

I tried 2nd and 3rd and yes, the warning goes away but then I test it with autofill service and the autofill does not work (when I test it with the attribute in the original layout, the autofill service does work).

So now I am trying to understand why does this happen so that I can fix it and properly use the style (as I would like to use this style on multiple places in the app).

Using `com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0`